# SWT Messagebox doesn't show on top

Tags: java

I did my first java app to run on a raspberry and I'm having difficult with messagebox.
When I press escape key it should appear asking if i really want to exit or not, but instead of appear on top of the main frame, the messagebox appear on the back of the main frame. If i press the messagebox buttons the correct actions occur. this is the code i wrote:

```
private void Mensagem()
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);


    int botoes = SWT.ICON_QUESTION |SWT.YES | SWT.NO;


    MessageBox mensagem = new MessageBox(shell, botoes);
    mensagem.setMessage("Deseja sair?");                
    int botao = mensagem.open();

    //System.out.println(mensagem.getParent());

    switch (botao) 
    {
        case SWT.YES:
          //System.out.println("SWT.YES");
          Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
          break;
        case SWT.NO:
          //System.out.println("SWT.NO");
          break;           
    }
    shell.pack();
    display.dispose();
}
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance,
Joaquim

Answer (score 1):

Add SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL to the flags when building the shell:

```
 new Shell(Display, SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

Failing it, maybe with SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL or SWT.SYSTEM_MODAL

Edit: I was wrong, it actually is SWT.ON_TOP

Comment: Thanks for the quickly reply. Nevertheless it doesn't work with these three options.

Comment: I already solve the issue. Instead of the three options suggested by fmcato, i use "SWT.ON_TOP" and it worrks!!!

Comment: I made a Runnable jar file and a jar file as well, and when i  run the app the messageBox don't appear?? It appears under development!! What is wrong with this?